# Embed kibana dashboard visualizations in Angular 10 application

Tags: angular, typescript, elasticsearch, kibana

Is there any tool or plugin which can be used to embed kibana visualization, in my angular 10 web application.?

Answer (score 0):

You can [share dashboard](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/dashboard.html#share-the-dashboard) as [embed code](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/reporting-getting-started.html#embed-code) using iFrame. Please check link for more information. below is discription mentioned in documentation.

> Display your dashboard or visualization on an internal company website
> or personal web page with an iframe. Embedding other Kibana objects is
> generally supported, but you might need to manually craft the proper
> HTML code.

Comment: Hi Sagar,

isnt there any way, i could setup buttons in my application page, upon click of which I could access those Pie charts or bar graph, rather then giving the complete access to the dashboard section to the client using iframe.

Comment: No there is no option to share only visulization. But what you can do is if you are using latest version of the elasticsearch then you can create the space and only specific dashbord into that space and share it. So client will have only access to the one dashbord  and not entire kibana access.

Comment: @SagarPatel is there a way I can embedd without using iframe

Comment: @sql_dummy I dont think so thats possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do that by querying iframe DOM and redirecting actions from your angular applications. To do that, iframe and the Angular app should be on same site (you can do reverse proxy) to prevent CORS and XSS. Please take a look at [this post](https://boringtechnology1.github.io/jekyll/update/2022/11/05/secured-kibana-dashboard-with-angular-and-spring-boot.html).